# configuring external block of IP addresses

Tags: ip, address, dsl, router

I have a business DSL through FairPoint. With it, I have a block of 5 IP addresses. I've done some googling and spoken with FP tech support. Perhaps someone that's more knowledgeable than I can provide some direction. I'm currently hosting my company's website on a Win2k3 server through FP's Westell modem and a Cyberoam router. My question is, what is the preferred or recommended configuration for setting up a Win2k8 server (or more) on one of the other IP addresses? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the public IP address attached directly to the W2k8 machine, or are happy with having it NATted to the server?

Comment: Mark - I contacted a cyberoam guru and he pointed me to this link -  http://kb.cyberoam.com/default.asp?SID=&Lang=1&id=1630 From this, I was able to use port forwarding to connect directly to my virtual server from the external IP address. This solved the problem for me. Not being a system guy, it appears that the terms in this KB article are generic enough to be used on most routers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your first step is getting one of the IPs set on the box.  This would be done via the normal way of configuring a static IP on the machine (if you aren't sure on how to do this, you may want to reconsider exposing a windows machine directly the internet).

After that, go into the TCP/IP properties, and hit 'Advanced'.  You can then add as many IPs as you want using the list at the top.